# Automatically change code with drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've trying to figure out how to change a HTML code with a drop-down menu.

This is what I currently have

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Languages</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" target="test">English</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=de" target="test">German</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=fr" target="test">French</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=es" target="test">Spanish</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=it" target="test">Italian</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

This changes the iFrame which is below the drop-down.

```
 <iframe name="test" src="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

Under the iFrame, I have a pre-code showing how to embed the above iFrame.

```
<pre><code>&lt;iframe&gt;src="Path of the zip file" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
          </code></pre>
```

Javascript I'm using

```
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to implement the link for where the iFrame folder is hosted to change when the user would click the drop-down menu and select a language?

For example, the user would click the drop-down menu and select German. The pre-code will display the iframe with the link to the german folder. (hope that makes sense)

If someone could assist me with this would be much appreciated.

**What I've tried and failed**

*Jquery*

```
 myFunction() {
    $("#myDropdown > a").on('click', function(){
        var url= $(this).attr('href'); //Get URL from a href
        var $iframe = $('#iframeId'); // Get Iframe id
        $iframe.attr('src',url);    // Insert new URL

        var v= $('#code').text(); //get Iframe inside code tags
        var code = jQuery('<div />').html(v).text(); //Convert to HTML object
        var n = $(code).attr("src",val); //change the src
        var fin = $(n).prop("outerHTML"); //get the HTML
        var finHTML = jQuery('<div />').text(fin).html(); //Convert HTML into HTML entities
        $('#code').text(finHTML); // Change code HTML
    });
}
```

*iFrame*

```
<iframe src="#" id="iframeId"></iframe>
```

*Export iFrame (in Text)*

```
<pre><code id="code">&lt;iframe src="Path of the <strong>zip file downloaded from email</strong>" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
  </code></pre>
```

I've tried the above but it disables the drop-down from working. Would **appreciate** if anyone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: Add a click handler for the links, and in there write the content of the href attribute into the innerHTML of the pre/code element …

Comment: @CBroe - Hi thanks for commenting, could you give me an example of what you mean? I'm not as you say a "pro" in Javascript.

Comment: Research the parts you’re unclear about, and then give it a try. If you encounter problems, update the question with a specific problem description.

Comment: @CBroe - It's quite confusing to understand something with no explanation. Would appreciate some help even if it's a website which gives me an example so I can learn.

Comment: You’re making things rather complicated, by trying to parse the text inside the pre element etc. Just use an additional element inside that, that holds only the address of the iframe (`src="<span id="foo">/path/goes/here</span>" ...`), and then replace the content of that. // If you tried stuff and it is not working, then please provide a [mcve], so that we can have a look at what’s wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will change the `src` of `iframe` inside `<pre>` according to the `href` of the clicked `<a>`.

```js
var myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
var links = myDropdown.getElementsByTagName('a'); // get all links inside #myDropdown

function changeSRC(e) {
  var link = e.target.href;    // get href of clicked link
  var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];
  code.innerHTML = '&lt;iframe&gt;src=&quot;'+link+'&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; seamless=&quot;seamless&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;';
}

for( var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', changeSRC);    // call changeSRC function when any link is clicked
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Languages</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" target="test">English</a>
    <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=de" target="test">German</a>
    <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=fr" target="test">French</a>
    <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=es" target="test">Spanish</a>
    <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=it" target="test">Italian</a>

  </div>
</div>
<pre>
  <code>&lt;iframe&gt;src="Path of the zip file" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much :D this was the answer I was looking for.. You are an absolute star!